# ImageButton call setImageDrawable() but get wrong size

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, image-resizing, android-imagebutton

I was writing an android application which contains a RecyclerView inside my ActivityMain. Each rows has an imageButton and a textLabel. In onBindViewHolder() method, I download an image from an URL and  after using setImageDrawable method, I change the image with the one that I just downloaded.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.textAuthor.setText(posts.get(position).getAuthorName());
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Get URL Image from my ArrayList Posts(which contains imageButton and textLabel)
                    URL url = new URL(posts.get(position).getImageView());
                    // Get inputStream from URL
                    InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) url.getContent();
                    // Create a drawable which contains my downloaded image
                    Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
                    // Change the image with the new one
                    holder.imageButton.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

All my ImageButton change image correctly downloading from their URL, but the problem is that they have wrong size until I scroll down and after a while I scroll up inside of my RecyclerView using my finger. It sounds like if I have to refresh my View but I don't know how to do this.

Note: all images have different size

I let you some images to explain better my problem:

[When I open my application and it starts to download image from URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXyki.png)

[When the download is completed the images have wrong size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF60u.png)

[If I scroll down and after I scroll up I get the images with the correct size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGwhd.png)

The rest of my codes is here: [MainActivty](https://pastebin.com/KrBT1zUX) [MyAdapter](https://pastebin.com/vWDQ8ASB) [PostClass](https://pastebin.com/19XncwRU) 
XML File which contains ImageButton: [my row of RecyclerView](https://pastebin.com/r4fW3j27)

Hope you can help me as always, thank you a lot!

EDIT: I have fixed downloading image using Glide!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code it worked for me

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/about" />
```

give your image button fixed height and width then it will work

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, the problem Is that all images have different size, so i can't set the width and height using xml